# Obtener RadioButton marcado a traves de json y modal

Tags: jquery, json

tengo un modal que cargo con los datos a través de un json, lo cual me trae los datos sin inconvenientes, lo que no me resulta es cuando vuelvo a abrir mi modal, lograr poner seleccionado el radiobutton que logicamente traigo a traves del json y por base de datos (Actualmente seleccionado Departamento).  Mi codigo json lo obtengo asi

```
$('.btnEdit').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            sit = $(this).attr('href');
            url="{{route('editar.JSON', ["id"=>"#REF#"])}}";
            url=url.replace("#REF#", $(this).attr('id'));
            $.getJSON(url, {}, function (data) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $('#formModal').attr('action', sit);
                $('#modal').modal('toggle');
                if(!data.Estado){
                    alert("Error");
                }else{
                    if((data.tipo)==1){
                        $('#est').html("Casa");
                    }else if((data.tipo)==2){
                        $('#est').html("Condominio");
                    }else if((data.tipo)==3){
                        $('#nwEstadoEv').html("Departamento");
                    }else if((data.tipo)==4){
                        $('#nwEstadoEv').html("Parcela");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

Y parte de mi modal es asi

```
<div>
   <label><input type="radio" class="form" name="tipo"  value="1">Casa</label>
</div>
<div>
   <label><input type="radio" class="form" name="tipo"  value="2">Condominio</label>
</div>
<div>
   <label><input type="radio" class="form" name="tipo"  value="3">Departamento</label>
</div>
<div>
   <label><input type="radio" class="form" name="tipo"  value="4">Condominio</label>
</div>
```

[image: Asi es como se ve mi modal]

Había tratado de usar `$('#seleccion').prop('checked')`, pero no he logrado absolutamente nada, si hago un `console.log(data.tipo);` me devuelve `3`, lo cual es correcto ya que pertenece a Deparmento, pero no logro que me deje seleccionado lo que ya traigo en mi codigo, como puedo hacerlo por favor

Comment: Como tus radio buttons no tienen id, puedes buscarlo por su valor. Algo así `$(":radio[value='3']").prop('checked', true);`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ gracias, pero no me funciona, también había probado asi $('input:radio[name=tipo]').is(':checked');, pero tampoco hace nada, me quedan los radio sin seleccionar.  También había probado dejando mi línea asi <input type="radio" class="form" name="tipo" id="seleccion"  value="4">Condominio y lo estaba reciebiendo asi $('#seleccion').attr('checked');, pero tampoco me resultó, salvo que yo este poniendo el código donde no corresponda

Comment: Ahí te dejé una respuesta con dos opciones que si le das a ejecutar verás que selecciona el radio con valor '3'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como tus radio buttons no tienen `id`, puedes buscarlo por su tipo y valor:

```js
$(":radio[value='3']").prop('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
<div>
   <label><input type="radio" class="form" name="tipo"  value="1">Casa</label>
</div>
<div>
   <label><input type="radio" class="form" name="tipo"  value="2">Condominio</label>
</div>
<div>
   <label><input type="radio" class="form" name="tipo"  value="3">Departamento</label>
</div>
<div>
   <label><input type="radio" class="form" name="tipo"  value="4">Condominio</label>
</div>
```

O por el nombre y valor:

```js
$("input[name=tipo][value='3']"). prop('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
<div>
   <label><input type="radio" class="form" name="tipo"  value="1">Casa</label>
</div>
<div>
   <label><input type="radio" class="form" name="tipo"  value="2">Condominio</label>
</div>
<div>
   <label><input type="radio" class="form" name="tipo"  value="3">Departamento</label>
</div>
<div>
   <label><input type="radio" class="form" name="tipo"  value="4">Condominio</label>
</div>
```

Aunque también podrías tomar el value directamente de la propiedad de tu json:

```js
let data = {tipo:"3"};
$(":radio[value=" + data.tipo + "]").prop('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
<div>
   <label><input type="radio" class="form" name="tipo"  value="1">Casa</label>
</div>
<div>
   <label><input type="radio" class="form" name="tipo"  value="2">Condominio</label>
</div>
<div>
   <label><input type="radio" class="form" name="tipo"  value="3">Departamento</label>
</div>
<div>
   <label><input type="radio" class="form" name="tipo"  value="4">Condominio</label>
</div>
```

o

```js
let data = {tipo:"3"};
$("input[name=tipo][value=" + data.tipo + "]"). prop('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
<div>
   <label><input type="radio" class="form" name="tipo"  value="1">Casa</label>
</div>
<div>
   <label><input type="radio" class="form" name="tipo"  value="2">Condominio</label>
</div>
<div>
   <label><input type="radio" class="form" name="tipo"  value="3">Departamento</label>
</div>
<div>
   <label><input type="radio" class="form" name="tipo"  value="4">Condominio</label>
</div>
```

Cualquiera de las opciones las puedes usar una vez que obtengas la respuesta a la llamada ajax:

```
$.getJSON(url, {}, function (data) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#formModal').attr('action', sit);
    $('#modal').modal('toggle');
    if(!data.Estado){
        alert("Error");
    }else{
        if((data.tipo)==1){
            $('#est').html("Casa");
        }else if((data.tipo)==2){
            $('#est').html("Condominio");
        }else if((data.tipo)==3){
            $('#nwEstadoEv').html("Departamento");
        }else if((data.tipo)==4){
            $('#nwEstadoEv').html("Parcela");
        }

        console.log(data.tipo);
        // Agrega esto 
        $(":radio[value=" + data.tipo + "]").prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

Comment: EStimado muchas gracias por la ayuda, pero disculpa que te moleste, pero al tomar el value directamente de la propiedad de mi json, en qué parte debo colocar el codigo, lo pregunto porque he intentado en ponerlo en diferentes partes y me muestra el modal vacio, las varibles se me pierden, en que parte de mi codigo debo implementar esto let data = {tipo:"3"};
$(":radio[value=" + data.tipo + "]").prop('checked', true);

Comment: Ah, claro, lo de ` let data = {tipo:"3"};` no va en tu código, sólo lo agregué aquí para emular el json que te devolvería la llamada ajax.

Comment: Edité la respuesta agregando tu ajax para que se vea más claro

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, ahora si me funciona, se agradece mucho, para rescatar un input me imagino que debo hacer lo mismo $(":input[value=" + data.fecha+ "]").val(); o me equivocó

Comment: Para el caso de un input podrías usar el nombre para encontrarlo y luego le asignas el valor que te llega en el json, algo así `$('input[name="nombre_del_input"]').val(data.fecha);`

Comment: Muchas gracias, me has salvado, la noción la tenía, pero no sabía como se pasaba el dato, mil gracais